# add on clause later on Promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to Javascript and Promise. I can understand when a Promise has on clause immediately as:

```
//example 1
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log("Hi")
  resolve("World")
}).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

but if the `then` clause is in separate statement as:

```
//example 2
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log("Hi")
  resolve("World")
});

 //at time t here

promise1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});

console.log("Hello");
```

then I'm a little bit confused because technically speaking, the statement before time t has already been executed, and when the `resolve("World")` get called, since there is no `then` clause "registered", so nothing should happen. After time t, `promise1.then(...)` executes, and it should not know that `resolve("World")` has been called. But the actual output does show that it know `resolve("World")` has been called.

So does it mean that the compiler does sth to assist here? for example, the compiler merge the `then` clause right after the promise1 statement just like example 1?

Comment: I don't think you're forced to use `then`. In your second snippet, you could use `await` to synhcronize the procedural execution of the code e.g. `let res = await promise1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the Promise object holds its state internally .
So when you call `.then` on a Promise object it will either :

- Await for resolution, and then fire the callback
- If the promise is already resolved, the callback will execute immediately

Comment: *"If the promise is already resolved, the callback will execute immediately"* No, the earliest moment the callback will be called is always in the next tick of the event loop.

Comment: But then they are inevitably going to wonder why in `promise.then(() => console.log('then')); console.log('after then');`, where `promise` is already resolved, `after then` is logged before `then`. I'm all for KISS, as long as it is correct.

Comment: I understand your point, I just don't think its a good idea to mention the event loop for example, at this context & time. But, that is like my 2 cents on the matter, if he really wants to "dig deeper" on this your answer is much more explanatory.

Comment: It's certainly a fine line to walk (keeping things simple while still being correct). And maybe sometimes it's better to look at both sides of the line instead... Anyways, we all do our best :)

Answer (score 1):

> So does it mean that the compiler does sth to assist here? for example, the compiler merge the then clause right after the promise1 statement just like example 1?

No, there is much less magic happening than you think. `new Promise` returns a promise object. A promise object has a `.then` method. You use this method to tell the promise that *once* it is resolved, call the passed function. The promise object holds onto this callback.

You can think of this as registering an event handler. Once the "resolve event" happens, the function is executed.

Of the course the promises itself knows whether or not it is resolved. So if `.then` is called on a resolved promise, it can immediately schedule the invocation of the callback.

Here is a very poor man's implementation of a promise (doesn't handle rejects and other things), which might give you a better idea of how promises work. Note that I use `setTimeout` here to simulate how promises always execute callbacks on the next tick of the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), but in reality JavaScript uses some other internal API:

```js
class Promise {
  constructor(handler) {
    this._callbacks = [];
    // Execute the passed handler, passing the "resolve" function
    handler(value => {
      // Mark the promise as resolved
      this._resolved = true;
      // Remember the value
      this._value = value;
      // Execute all registered callbacks
      this._callbacks.forEach(cb => cb(value));
    });
  }
  
  then(handler) {
    let _resolve;
    const promise = new Promise(resolve => _resolve = resolve);
    const callback = value => {    
      setTimeout(
        () => _resolve(handler(value)),
        0
      );
    };
    
    // Is the promise already resolved?
    if (this._resolved) {
      // Immediately schedule invocation of handler with the remembered value
      callback(this._value);
    } else {
      // Remember callback for future invocation
      this._callbacks.push(callback);
    }
    
    return promise;
  }
}

const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log('inside Promise');
  resolve(42);
});

console.log('in between');

promise.then(v => {
  console.log('inside then', v);
})

promise.then(v => {
  console.log('inside another then', v);
  return 21;
})
.then(v => {
  console.log('.then returns a new promise', v);
});
```